# Custom Layout doesn't show up on Screen

Tags: java, vaadin

I tried making this tutorial work by just copying it to the letter.

It didn't have the folders entirely right so I just put them in the right ones.

In my: `/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/layouts` folder I have the `my-layout.html` file. Which looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div location="top" id="top"></div>
        <div>
            <span location="bottom" id="bottom"></span>
            <span location="left" id="left"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my Java file it looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    CustomLayout layout = new CustomLayout("my-layout");
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    layout.addComponent(menuBar, "top");
    layout.addComponent(new Button("Does Nothing"), "bottom");

    VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    vLayout.addComponent(new InlineDateField());
    vLayout.addComponent(new TextField("", "Nothing to put in here"));
    vLayout.setSpacing(true);
    vLayout.setMargin(true);
    vLayout.setVisible(true);

    layout.addComponent(vLayout, "left");
    layout.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I run this on the Jetty Server through netbeans, the site doesn't show any of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set your layout as content in the UI:

```
setContent(layout)
```